# Swift / SwiftUI unique dictionary value

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm having a challenge with generating a distinct list of variables from a dictionary received from an API.

The data received is an array of:

```
struct ContactDetails: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var company, name, email, phone, mobile, city, region: String
}
```

I am displaying the data in a view as follows:

```
let results = ...array of the ContactDetails received
        if results != nil {
            List {
                ForEach(results ?? [], id: \.self) { result in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProjectContactDetailsView(company: result.company, results: results ?? [])) {
                        Text(result.company)
                            .tag(result.id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In many instances I am receiving 30 to 40 of these results, and some are contacts from the same company. As you can see I am linking to a new view with more details based on the company name where I will list the individuals. How do I reduce or get a distinct list of the company names?

I have tried:

using an extension:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func unique() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var seen: Set<Iterator.Element> = []
        return filter { seen.insert($0).inserted }
    }
}
```

But I can't get this sequencing correct:

```
ForEach(results ?? [], id: \.self) { result in
                   ForEach(result.company.unique()) { company in
                       NavigationLink(destination: ProjectContactDetailsView(company: result.company, results: results ?? [])) {
                           Text(result.company)
                               .tag(result.id)
                       }
                   }
               }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `result.company` is not a array, try this:
     `ForEach(results.map{$0.company}.unique(), id: \.self) { company in ...`

Comment: Thank you WD, I unfortunately am getting the same errors here as I am with Matt: Value of type '[ContactDetails]' has no member 'company' & Value of type 'Optional<_>' has no member 'unique'

Answer (score -2):

Got it working as follows:

```
    struct ProjectContactSubContractorView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var env: Env

    var body: some View {

        let results = env.project.response?.container?.project?.subcontractors?.contact

        if let results = results {

            let groupedByCompany = Dictionary(grouping: results, by: { $0.company })

            List {

                ForEach(groupedByCompany.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { company in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ProjectContactDetailsView(company: company, results: groupedByCompany[company] ?? [])) {
                        Text(company)
                    }
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a duplicate of my answer?

Comment: Joakim, thanks I couldn't get it working with your exact answer but you gave me the framework I needed, thank you

Comment: Of course you didn’t since it wasn’t enough information in the question to provide a complete solution. I don’t want to request points but if my answer helped you solve the problem then it should be marked as accepted rather than you posting this answer. Also I believe it’s better to access the values from `env` in a view modifier like I suggested rather than writing the code in the body.